# Failed to connect hypersonic(HSQLDB) DB on Apache 7.0

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jdbc, hsqldb

I have a project in Eclipse which is defined as 'Dynamic web project' on Apache-Tomcat 7.0 server.
I need to connect to `hypersonic` DB (HSQLDB) in some of my Java classses.

The code which i'm trying to make is very simple:

```
private Connection getConnection(){
    Connection conn;

    try {   
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        conn = driverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost","sa","");
        return conn;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return null;
}
```

I already added `hsqldb.jar` to some `lib` library which located in my project and defined in the `Java build path` over Eclipse.

The problem is that I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1722)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at root.login.getConnection(login.java:75)
    at root.login.doPost(login.java:35)
```

So it cannot find the `org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver` class for some reason.
I have to say that I made this configuration many times before that, and it all went well.

> **Funny story:** 
>  I managed to have another simple Java project with main function and this function over the same configuration, and
>   it went well on the exact same machine.

- What can I do in order to find this class?
- Is there any more information that I need to tell you to make it clearer?

Comment: In a web application, you have to add hsqldb.jar into `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the application (or into `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` folder, if you have more webapps using it). To have it just in Eclipse project's classpath is not enough.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek helped me so much! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a web application, you have to add the `hsqldb.jar` file into `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the application (or into `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` folder, if you have more webapps using it). To have it just in Eclipse project's classpath is not enough.