# Class.forName() - are there other ways to use it?

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

Continuously this thread:
[Failed to connect hypersonic(HSQLDB) DB on Apache 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32101108/failed-to-connect-hypersonichsqldb-db-on-apache-7-0)

I need to know if there are some other new ways to use `Class.forName()` function.

Is there a way to load a class from a certain jar ?

Comment: `Class.forName()` will try and locate your the specified class in your classpath. You can't specify the jar to look in, you can only specify which jars are part of the classpath or not.

Comment: OK, but what are the possible cases that the class loader cannot load a class ?

Comment: Provided you have the right fully qualified class name, the only reason is that the specified class is not found in the classpath.

Comment: There is only one reason the class loader cannot load a class, and that is the classloader is not configured such that it can find the class.  99% of the time it's because the JAR file is not on the classpath, or is not readable.  The other 1% of the time deals with exotic class loaders, like those you might find in a WAR / EAR container "server", like JBoss, Tomcat, etc.  In those cases, the specification of how to package these items assure that the right JAR files will be found in those environments.  Beyond that, you must write your own classloader and it has a bug in it :)

Comment: Could you give me more info about cases with `Apache`?

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor The Apache organization makes many products.  Care to specify which one?

Answer (score 0):

For JDBC and other services (in the sense of services to the application, not OSGI services), there is [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) which will load classes based on the classpath, and if any of the jar files on the classpath offer to provide "implementations" of the "abstract" service.

Older ways have a DriverManager, which is basically a Collection of possible services.  This is the pattern being shown in your example, where creating an instance of the class typically forces the "static initializer" block to run.  That block will typically look something like.

```
public class MyService implements Service {
  static {
     ServiceRegistry.register(new MyService());
  } 
}
```

or for JDBC in particular

```
public class MyDriver implements Driver{
  static {
     DriverManager.registerDriver(new MyDriver());
  } 
}
```

In JDBC the driver manager then goes through the list of registered services, asking each one if they provide connections for the "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://...." connection string.

If you cannot rely on the static initializer block, and you're dealing with JDBC in particular, you can (assuming you can load the class somehow) call the methods to register an instance in the DriverManager, with registerDriver(...); but, you can easily see the patterns involved.