# MariaDB connector for JDBC for querying a database created in PhPMyAdmin

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb

I have created a database named `vidya` with a table named `students` using `PhPMyAdmin`. I want to insert values to the database using a Java code. Here's the code but currently has problem with `MariaDB` `JDBC connector` plus I am not sure if my `DB_URL` is correct anyways if it is running on the localhost.

```
/**
 * Created by jalal on 7/6/2016.
 */
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TestPhpMyAdmin
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            // create a mysql database connection
            String myDriver = "org.mariadb.jdbc";

            String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/vidya";
            Class.forName(myDriver);

            //  Database credentials
            final String USER = "root";
            final String PASS = "newpass";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

            // the mysql insert statement
            String query = " insert into students (ID, last_name, first_name, birthday, hometown)"
                    + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 808027);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "Davis");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "Felicita");
            preparedStatement.setDate(4, startDate);
            preparedStatement.setString(5, "Venice");

            // execute the preparedstatement
            preparedStatement.execute();

            conn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
org.mariadb.jdbc
```

Here's the directory structure:
[image]

`MariaDB`'s version is `10.1.13-MariaDB`

Comment: You get that error because `org.mariadb.jdbc` is not the name of a class to load, but of a package, which you can't load with `Class.forName`. You should have used `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`. But as you found out, loading the driver yourself is not actually necessary anymore.

Comment: The `Class.forName(myDriver)` line has not been required since 2007. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC drivers register themself with [DriverManager.registerDriver](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#registerDriver-java.sql.Driver-).

Using [DriverManager.getConnection(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-), DriverManager will asked each driver if url like 'jdbc:mariadb:..." is handled. If a driver answer is yes, Drivermanager will create a connection using this Driver.

(That will permit to have for example a H2 database for developpement environnement, and a MariaDB database for production just changing the url)

Driver for MariaDB is "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver", not "org.mariadb.jdbc" that is the driver package, but in fact isn't usefull in this case. This portion of code that is causing the error can be suppressed :

```
    String myDriver = "org.mariadb.jdbc";
    Class.forName(myDriver);
```

Comment: `org.mariadb.jdbc` is the driver *package*, not its classpath.

Answer (score 0):

According to `ojacobson` in Java IRC channel there's no need for `Class.forName(myDriver);` hence I commented it and the value was inserted onto the database table:

Here's the correct code for the reference:

```
/**
 * Created by jalal on 7/6/2016.
 */
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TestPhpMyAdmin
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // create a mysql database connection
            String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/vidya";

            //  Database credentials
            final String USER = "root";
            final String PASS = "newpass";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

            // the mysql insert statement
            String query = " insert into students (ID, last_name, first_name, birthday, hometown)"
                    + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 808027);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "Davis");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "Felicita");
            preparedStatement.setDate(4, startDate);
            preparedStatement.setString(5, "Venice");

            // execute the preparedstatement
            preparedStatement.execute();

            conn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [a Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106052/class-forname-are-there-other-ways-to-use-it#comment52106990_32106052) and [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8053125) , and somehow with your setup, it interfered.

Answer (score 0):

For mariadb is: jdbc:mariadb://localhost/ and don't need classforname if your java version above 1.6
ClassForName is for java below 1.6.

Change this line:

import java.sql.*;

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

And java.sql.Date make change for Date only.

Don't use import java.sql.*;